# disable textbox when drawer opens up by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

**update 1 :** I further removed all the unnecessary files, can you guys help me  https://codesandbox.io/s/0pk0z5prqn

- I am trying to diable a textbox.
- when I click the advanced sports search button a drawer opens in that I am trying to display a textbox.
- toggleDrawer method and

  but the problem is I am not getting the state in  sports-advanced-search.js file, thats where I disable textbox.

  I debugged by putting console but still not helping me 'console.log("this.state--->", this.state);'

  Can you tell me how to fix it, so that in future I will fix it myself.

  Providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/q8o66x572w

**tab-demo.js**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: 0,
      top: false,
      left: false,
      bottom: false,
      right: false,
      disabled: false
    };
  }
  toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
    this.setState({
      [side]: open
    });
    this.setState({ disabled: !this.state.disabled });
  };



   <Button onClick={this.toggleDrawer("right", true)}>
                  Advanced Sports Search
                </Button>
```

**sports-advanced-search.js**

```
 render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;
    console.log("this.state--->", this.state);

                <input
              name="firstname"
              type="text"
              disabled={this.state.disabled ? "disabled" : ""}
            />
```

Comment: When sharing a CodeSandbox with your question, it should contain the [minimal amount of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) necessary to reproduce the problem described in your question.

Comment: An appropriate sandbox for this problem would have a Drawer, the input you want to disable, and a button. It could probably all be in one file. Start a new sandbox with just this and you may even find you can fix it yourself.

Comment: @RyanCogswell  hey I updated the Abhijith code changes but still its not working...providing the updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/0pk0z5prqn

Comment: Create a new, minimal sandbox as my previous comments indicated.

Comment: @RyanCogswell hey I cleaned tab-demo.js and sports-advanced-search.js file, is that fine https://codesandbox.io/s/0pk0z5prqn

Comment: @nosrr No, that is not fine. I would expect you to create a brand new empty React CodeSandbox and include the absolute minimum amount of code (Drawer, input, button as I indicated before) and for you to spend several hours trying to work through this on your own. Then if in that minimal sandbox you are still experiencing a specific problem that you can't figure out, then ask a question about that specific problem. If you do not expend more effort on isolating your problem and working through it on your own, you will never react that future point where you can "fix it yourself".

Comment: @Ryan I further removed all the unnecessaryu files, can you help me now https://codesandbox.io/s/0pk0z5prqn

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186870/discussion-between-ryan-cogswell-and-no-ssr).

Comment: @Ryan I am not able to chat, can you post it in the comments

Comment: What do you mean you are "not able to chat"? You just click on the link and continue comments there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass "disabled" as string. HTML disabled attribute is boolean. So, just `disabled={this.state.disabled}` should be enough.

Comment: Hey that's the reason I mentioned the file name and method name... can you help me

Comment: @nossr What is confusing about updating that one line of code?

Comment: @Abhijith hey I updated the code changes but still its not working...providing the updated code here https://codesandbox.io/s/0pk0z5prqn